# R.js optimizer excuding angular library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs

i'm having trouble using the r.js optimizer to optimize an angular project.

I'm trying to use the grunt-requirejs to optimize and it works perfectly until i try to exclude angular from the build. Then I get an error in angular route that says angular is undefined. I want to do this so i can load angular from a cdn but include angular-route in the app.

How come angular-route doesn't wait until angular is loaded?

I know angular gets loaded but does anyone know why is angular route is run before that, and how to fix it?

#### app

```
define(['angular', ...], function(angular){
...
});
```

#### public/js/requirejs-config.js:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    angular: {
      exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-route': [
      'angular'
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    angular: '../../bower_components/angular/angular',
    'angular-route': '../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route'
  }
});

require(['app']);
```

#### Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "public/js",
                    name: "app",
                    mainConfigFile: "public/js/requirejs-config.js",
                    out: "public/js/combined.js",
                    paths: {
                        angular: "empty:" //without this it works fine
                    },
                    optimize: "none"
                }
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-requirejs');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by myself.

I needed to use wrapShim and specify the dependecies with deps instead of an array.

#### app

```
define(['angular', ...], function(angular){
...
});
```

#### public/js/requirejs-config.js:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    angular: {
      exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-route': {
      deps: ['angular']
    }
  },
  paths: {
    angular: '../../bower_components/angular/angular',
    'angular-route': '../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route'
  }
});

require(['app']);
```

#### Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "public/js",
                    name: "app",
                    mainConfigFile: "public/js/requirejs-config.js",
                    out: "public/js/combined.js",
                    paths: {
                        angular: "empty:" //without this it works fine
                    },
                    wrapShim: true,
                    optimize: "none"
                }
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-requirejs');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);

};
```

Comment: do you mind sharing your seed project if you have any? Or any blog post to do this? I am trying to do this optimization and stuck with it for a while. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't work at the same company anymore and I don't have access to the source code. I hope you manage to solve it anyhow